# Keep rows in data frame that, for all combinations of the values of certain columns, contain the same elements in another column

Tags: python, pandas, filter, combinations

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['x','x','x','x','x','y','y','y','y','y'],'b':['z','z','z','w','w','z','z','w','w','w'],'c':['c1','c2','c3','c1','c3','c1','c3','c1','c2','c3'],'d':range(1,11)})

   a  b   c   d
0  x  z  c1   1
1  x  z  c2   2
2  x  z  c3   3
3  x  w  c1   4
4  x  w  c3   5
5  y  z  c1   6
6  y  z  c3   7
7  y  w  c1   8
8  y  w  c2   9
9  y  w  c3  10
```

how can I keep only the rows that, for all combinations of `a` and `b`, contain the same values in `c`? Or in other words, how to exclude rows with `c` values that are only present in some combinations of `a` and `b`?

For example, only `c1` and `c3` are present in all combinations of `a` and `b` (`[x,z]`,`[x,w]`,`[y,z]`,`[y,w]`), so the output would be

```
   a  b   c   d
0  x  z  c1   1
2  x  z  c3   3
3  x  w  c1   4
4  x  w  c3   5
5  y  z  c1   6
6  y  z  c3   7
7  y  w  c1   8
9  y  w  c3  10
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way. Get unique lists per group and then check common elements across all the returned arrays using `reduce` and `np.intersect1d`. Then filter the dataframe using `series.isin` and `boolean indexing`

```
from functools import reduce
out = df[df['c'].isin(reduce(np.intersect1d,df.groupby(['a','b'])['c'].unique()))]
```

---

Breakdown:

```
s = df.groupby(['a','b'])['c'].unique()
common_elements = reduce(np.intersect1d,s)
#Returns :-> array(['c1', 'c3'], dtype=object)

out = df[df['c'].isin(common_elements )]#.copy()
```

---

```
   a  b   c   d
0  x  z  c1   1
2  x  z  c3   3
3  x  w  c1   4
4  x  w  c3   5
5  y  z  c1   6
6  y  z  c3   7
7  y  w  c1   8
9  y  w  c3  10
```

Answer (score 10):

Lets try `groupby` with `nunique` to count of unique elements per column `c` group:

```
s = df['a'] + ',' + df['b'] # combination of a, b
m = s.groupby(df['c']).transform('nunique').eq(s.nunique())
```

---

```
df[m]

   a  b   c   d
0  x  z  c1   1
2  x  z  c3   3
3  x  w  c1   4
4  x  w  c3   5
5  y  z  c1   6
6  y  z  c3   7
7  y  w  c1   8
9  y  w  c3  10
```

Comment: `add` is not really safe, it would confuse `('aa', 'b')` with `('a', 'ab')`

Comment: @QuangHoang True. How about using an seperator like `df['a'] + ',' + df['b']`

Comment: That'll be sensitive to `,` inside the field. Better do with `tuple`.

Comment: @QuangHoang That's very edge case, I think in that case using more complex seperator should work fine as well.

Answer (score 9):

Try something diff `crosstab`

```
s = pd.crosstab([df['a'],df['b']],df.c).all()
out = df.loc[df.c.isin(s.index[s])]
Out[34]: 
   a  b   c   d
0  x  z  c1   1
2  x  z  c3   3
3  x  w  c1   4
4  x  w  c3   5
5  y  z  c1   6
6  y  z  c3   7
7  y  w  c1   8
9  y  w  c3  10
```

Answer (score 8):

Let's try pivot the table, then drop `NA`, which means a value is missing in the combination:

```
all_data =(df.pivot(index=['a','b'], columns='c', values='c')
             .loc[:, lambda x: x.notna().all()]
             .columns)
df[df['c'].isin(all_data)]
```

Output:

```
   a  b   c   d
0  x  z  c1   1
2  x  z  c3   3
3  x  w  c1   4
4  x  w  c3   5
5  y  z  c1   6
6  y  z  c3   7
7  y  w  c1   8
9  y  w  c3  10
```

Comment: @anky probably pivot does not allow same `column` and `values`. Use `values='d'` and `aggfunc='size'` with `pivot_table` instead.

Answer (score 7):

We can use `groupby` + `size` and then `unstack`, which will fill `NaN` for groups of ['a', 'b'] that are missing a 'c' group. Then we `dropna` and subset the original DataFrame to the `c` values that survive the dropna.

```
df[df.c.isin(df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c']).size().unstack(-1).dropna(axis=1).columns)]

   a  b   c   d
0  x  z  c1   1
2  x  z  c3   3
3  x  w  c1   4
4  x  w  c3   5
5  y  z  c1   6
6  y  z  c3   7
7  y  w  c1   8
9  y  w  c3  10
```

---

The result of the groupby operation contains columns only for groups of `c` that exist in all unique combinations of `['a', 'b']`, so we just grab the columns attribute.

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c']).size().unstack(-1).dropna(axis=1)

#c     c1   c3
#a b          
#x w  1.0  1.0
#  z  1.0  1.0
#y w  1.0  1.0
#  z  1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use list comprehension with `str.contains`:

```
unq = [[x, len(df[(df[['a','b','c']].agg(','.join, axis=1)).str.contains(',' + x)]
                   .drop_duplicates())] for x in df['c'].unique()]
keep = [lst[0] for lst in unq if lst[1] == max([lst[1] for lst in unq])]
df = df[df['c'].isin(keep)]
df

   a  b   c   d
0  x  z  c1   1
2  x  z  c3   3
3  x  w  c1   4
4  x  w  c3   5
5  y  z  c1   6
6  y  z  c3   7
7  y  w  c1   8
9  y  w  c3  10
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make the below assumptions this works to give you which elements of column c to keep:

```
df.groupby("c")["a"].count() == df.groupby("c")["a"].count().max()
```

Output:

```
c
c1     True
c2    False
c3     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Assumptions:

1. There are no duplicates
2. There is at least one value for column c that contains all combinations of a and b.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) and get all combinations of `a` and `b`:

```
vc = df[['a', 'b']].drop_duplicates().value_counts()
```

Result:

```
a  b
y  z    1
   w    1
x  z    1
   w    1
```

Then you can compare counts for each group with `vc` and [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) out groups with missing combinations:

```
df.groupby('c').filter(lambda x: x[['a', 'b']].value_counts().ge(vc).all())
```

Output:

```
   a  b   c   d
0  x  z  c1   1
2  x  z  c3   3
3  x  w  c1   4
4  x  w  c3   5
5  y  z  c1   6
6  y  z  c3   7
7  y  w  c1   8
9  y  w  c3  10
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming there are 4 distinct values as per the example:

A simple solution can be :

```
df[df['a'].groupby(df['c']).transform('count').eq(4)]
```